# Accessing a Go slice without panicking

Tags: go, slice

How can I access a slice without panicking when it doesn't have enough elements?

I have the following code:

```golang
str = str[:3]
```

but since its content can vary in length, when it has less than 3 elements it crashes the whole program. Is there any way to ignore it? In Javascript I can use the `slice` method without this issue. For example:

```js
str = str.slice(0, 3);
```

would slice the string even if its length is less than 3.

Comment: Check the capacity of the slice before attempting to slice it: `if cap(s) >= 3 { str = str[:3] }`.

Comment: You can simply check the slice size with `len` as I assume you only want your valid inserted data in the slice: `if len(s) >= 3 { str = str[:3] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function that emulates the behaviour of [JavaScript's `slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) would be convenient for you, you could easily write a generic (Go 1.21+) one:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, 1, 4))  // output: [2, 3]
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, 2, 1))  // output: []
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, 5, 7))  // output: []
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, -2, 1)) // output: [1]
}

func Slice[S ~[]T, T any](s S, lo, hi int) S {
    if hi <= lo {
        return nil
    }
    lo = clip(0, lo, cap(s))
    hi = clip(0, hi, cap(s))
    return s[lo:hi]
}

func clip(lo, a, hi int) int {
    return max(lo, min(a, hi))
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zHStpHXfFsh))

---

And if, for some reason, you cannot yet migrate to Go 1.21+, here is a version compatible with Go 1.18+:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, 1, 4))  // output: [2, 3]
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, 2, 1))  // output: []
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, 5, 7))  // output: []
    fmt.Println(Slice(s, -2, 1)) // output: [1]
}

func Slice[S ~[]T, T any](s S, lo, hi int) S {
    if hi <= lo {
        return nil
    }
    lo = clip(0, lo, cap(s))
    hi = clip(0, hi, cap(s))
    return s[lo:hi]
}

func clip(lo, a, hi int) int {
    return max(lo, min(a, hi))
}

func max(a, b int) int {
    if a > b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}

func min(a, b int) int {
    if a < b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/OZHoB-pJRRH?v=goprev))

Comment: This panics if called like this: `SafelySlice([]int{1, 2, 3}, 2, 1)`